# Don't feed the trolls! Just flag them

Tags: discussion, editing, spam

Lately, we are receiving abusive questions and answers from some spammers. They are targeting gods, users in their posts. Yes, it is hurting for many people. This is causing some people to reply to those posts in the comments, some are editing their posts, some are answering those questions in the comments out of frustration. These do not have any effect on those trolls.

If you have come across them, **[just flag as Rude/Abusive. Don't feed them](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/flagging)**. Replying to them will only encourage them. Main motto of those trolls is to create a disturbance in religion and make the users feel bad. Replying to them will only reach their goal. Let us not make happen what they intend. Just flag the post as Rude/Abusive. Don't edit or reply them.

#### What happens if there is an edit to spam post?

- It invalidates the spam flags cast on the edited version.
- It makes search a bit difficult for moderators while nuking the account later.
- Community doesn't know if it is a spam or just a Not An Answer.

This makes a difference because rude/abusive and spam flags delete posts but other flags do not. This delays flagging and deletion of spam content. So, it results in the spam post stay on the site longer.

For more reasons see:

- [Should spam posts be edited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110030/357396) from Meta Stack Exchange.
- [Should we edit out spam from spam posts?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/3574/874027) from Meta Super User.
- [Should I edit a pure abusive/offensive post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359869/9379355)
- [Let's talk about handling spam or rude/abusive posts](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11541/83884)

We want spam and offensive content to be nuked as soon as possible.

#### Anonymous edit suggestions:

Most of you know that there are trolls frequently vandalizing questions and answers with their offensive edits. Users with a minimum reputation of 1000 are able to review these edit suggestions. When you find them, select "**Reject**" and select the first option "**spam**". Do not select other options while rejecting. If you see a mistake in the post which needs to be corrected, *please* wait for some time. Wait till the edit is rejected as spam and then edit later. Selecting "Improve edit" approves the edit by troll and selecting "Reject and Edit" does not impose penalties on the troll like immediate ban on the troll for further edit suggestions. It delays the process.

We are running low on reviewers. Active reviewers are reaching their limit of review but the edits are still pending. Please stay active in the [reviews](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/review) especially in [Suggested edits](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/) review.

Comment: And also it isn't worth voting to delete them. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359869/should-i-edit-a-pure-abusive-offensive-post/359870#359870

Comment: Yes, added one more post into the question.

Comment: Can't stackexchange track the user editing all the questions with offensive wordings again and again and ban him for his actions. Is there a count that they take into consideration such that if a person's edits are rejected let's say 50 times as Spam, then the user is just a spammer and should be banned.

Comment: @Aby Yes, mods ban the IP address immediately when there are certain spam edits. But this editor is using some VPN or Tor.