# Should we allow anonymous user edit?

Tags: feature-request

Recently Trolls from anonymous account actively started participating in editing post and adding abusing words to it. Since those users are anonymous, we can't take proper action. But it should be doable to restrict anonymous user to edit any post.

One Example of one of these edits: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/20636

Comment: Related:https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140935/260388

Comment: I think this feature should be fine, It's just a privilege that we are not supposed to give to anonymous user just like we restrict it for low rep registered users.  @Pandya

Comment: I am shocked how could [Suresh](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/20636) approve the edit.. is he the one who is trolling? like editing as anonymous and then approving from a high rep account?

Comment: @Mr_Green I think it is done by mistake. I found another approve like this. Similarly, There was another suggested edit which was rejected as spam by one user but it was proper. Approved later by community.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As well as the *nice* moderation, StackExchange also welcomes some contributions from unregistered users e.g. posting Q/A and improving posts. But unfortunately we [have been getting](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/sites/dash?utf8=%E2%9C%93&site_id=249&months=2&tab=all) trolls recently and hence we've been occasionally implementing the restriction for posts from unregistered users:

[image]

Now, talking about anonymous attempt to inject trolls by editing posts, that is less harmful since it requires to pass from the [review](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits) process. Obviously such trolls are subjected to rejection and **insta-ban**.

As mentioned in [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/260388):

> #### What about abuse or bad edits?
>
> There are strict limits enforced. If a user (anonymous or registered) submits many rejected edits they will be automatically banned from suggesting edits. **Anonymous users can also be instantly banned if they suggest an edit that trips a filter (explained below)**. Finally, moderators can manually ban users from suggesting edits.
>
> In addition, in order to reduce the incentive for spammers to make spam edits that get rejected, suggested edit spam is hidden from logged-out users, so they can't show their clients public-facing pages with spam (so they won't get paid).

And rejection of anonymous suggested-edit as a spam is subjected to instant ban.

> Because a large proportion of anonymous edits are spam or abusive, **anonymous edits are heavily rate-limited and there is an extra filter that checks all anonymous edits.** If your edit trips the filter, it will be silently disregarded and you will be **instantly banned** from suggesting edits temporarily.

Thus, there are very less chances for such trolls to enter into the system through `improve this question` or `improve this answer` button.

---

Likewise [suggested to flag posts](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1323/277) trolls, reject such trolls as spam whenever shown in [the review queue](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits).

Comment: I still don't understand why to give anonymous user that privilege that we don't even give to registered user with less rep.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Registered users with less reputation can also suggest an edit.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Which privilege do you mean user with low reputation doesn't have but an unregistered one has?

Comment: Editing a post. That's what my question is about. Isn't it ?

Comment: @The Editing a post which goes to review is not a privilege. It is possible with 1 rep also. Q, A, edit are basic.

Comment: Ohk! But we can allow only privileged user to do edit, let's say if user earned 50 rep, he can do edit else not. @Sarv

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto why to place such restrictions at all? It will go throw review and we do have good reviewers so I can't see any issues.

Comment: Why not ? If it's reducing at least a little of unnecessary effort. @AnkitSharma

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto it's also eliminating the chance of useful feedback

Comment: @AnkitSharma Why? If someone wants to give a useful feedback, they can get registered and can give n number of feedback, no one is stopping 'em to.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto but SE wants to give them freedom not force them to register

Comment: That's why I put a feature request :) @AnkitSharma

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto but still it feel unnecessary and doesn't seem that urgent to make SE do custom setting for a beta site.

Comment: You're right that it's not urgent for a beta site. Also I am not forcing anyone to enable it asap. I am just asking for a feature, Either it can be enabled or not, It's upto SE to decide. Proposing a valid request not bad, is it? @AnkitSharma

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto that's what meta is for but when we come to meta we have to be ready for reverse opinion/suggestions too.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Sure